# How to set default value for a proc argument to be a new dictionary in Tcl

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I would like to write a *proc* which can accept *dict* as an [optional argument](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl12.html) or create new if none was given. My attempt, however, fails with

> too many fields in argument specifier "dictionary [dict create]"

```tcl
proc getOpts { {dictionary [dict create]} } {
    upvar $dictionary dct
    for { set i 0 } { $i < $::argc } { incr i } {
        set key [lindex $::argv $i]
        if { [string index $key 0] == "-" } {
            incr i
            dict set dct [string trimleft $key "-"] [lindex $::argv $i]
        } else {
            dict set dct $key ""
        }
    }
}
```

As [dictionaries are pure values](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl23a.html), I thought this could work. It looks I might have been wrong. Still, I would like to know why it doesn’t work.

Comment: Just use {}.   But your upvar will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that the argument variable list is a true list, not a command evaluation context. That means the `[dict create]` is getting parsed as two separate words, and `proc` doesn't like that.  Fortunately, a `dict create` with no other arguments is just another way of saying the empty string: use `{}` or `""` instead.

The bigger problem is that you are using that with `upvar`; you probably don't want to do that. The right approach is likely to be to not do the variable binding, and instead to just return the dictionary from the procedure: the caller can save it in one of its own variables if it cares to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if `proc` has an optional parameter I cannot use it for passing information back to the caller because I cannot do `upvar` on it, right?

Comment: @Mr.Tao: 1) you can pass information back to the caller in any case, by returning a value. 2) It's not the optional parameter value that causes problems with `upvar`: the thing is that the arguments to `upvar` (after the optional level argument) need to be variable names.

Comment: @PeterLewerin By _it_ I’ve been referring to the optional parameter, not to the `proc` itself.

Comment: @Mr.Tao: you can always use an optional parameter in upvar, but in this case it is unlikely to be helpful as the value will be a dictionary value. Unless you have a variable whose name is equal to the dictionary value, there is nothing to link to. If you want to share a dictionary between caller and callee, you should pass the name (and upvar using that) instead of the value.